# Applying a template in XSLT and does not work

Tags: xslt

I'm new to XSLT and i'm trying to apply a template to a certain node which is reached via nested for-each functions.

I have tried to simplify it and moved the apply-templates in only 1 for-each and there i got it to work.

This is my sample input xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<getPartMasterDataCompleteResponse >
    <result>
        <partMasterDataCompletes>
            <partMasterDataComplete>
                <part>A0001506450</part>
                <version>11</version>
                <partMasterData>
                    <language>german</language>
                    <part>A1234567890</part>
                    <releaseDateFrom>2018-09-06T08:52:18+02:00</releaseDateFrom>
                    <testTag>
                        <test></test>
                        <test></test>
                        <test></test>
                    </testTag>
                </partMasterData>
            </partMasterDataComplete>
        </partMasterDataCompletes>
    </result>
</getPartMasterDataCompleteResponse>
```

This is the xslt i'm using:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="getPartMasterDataCompleteResponse/result/partMasterDataCompletes">
        <xsl:for-each select="partMasterDataComplete">
            <Part>
                <UserData>
                    <xsl:for-each select="partMasterData/*">
                        <xsl:if test="not(*)">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'part'">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="part"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <UserValue>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="title">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                    </UserValue>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </UserData>
            </Part>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="part">
        <UserValue title="PartNumber">
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </UserValue>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result i get from Online-transformation tools is:

```xml
<Part>
   <UserData>
      <UserValue title="language" value="german"/>
      <UserValue title="releaseDateFrom" value="2018-09-06T08:52:18+02:00"/>
   </UserData>
</Part>
```

What i would expect is:

```xml
<Part>
   <UserData>
      <UserValue title="language" value="german"/>
      <UserValue title="PartNumber" value="A0001506450"/>
      <UserValue title="releaseDateFrom" value="2018-09-06T08:52:18+02:00"/>
   </UserData>
</Part>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do apply-templates, you are already positioned on a `part` element, so by doing `<xsl:apply-templates select="part"/>` you are actually looking for a child element called `part` on the current element. (i.e. it is actually the same as doing `<xsl:apply-templates select="child::part"/>`)

You want to apply the template to the current element, so do this instead:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
```

Or, if you really wanted to make it explicit...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="self::part"/>
```

As an aside, you can simplify your XSLT greatly, by better use of `xsl:apply-templates` and by using Attribute Value Templates to create attributes.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="getPartMasterDataCompleteResponse/result/partMasterDataCompletes">
        <xsl:for-each select="partMasterDataComplete">
            <Part>
                <UserData>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="partMasterData/*[not(*)]" />
                </UserData>
            </Part>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="partMasterData/*">
        <UserValue title="{local-name()}" value="{current()}" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="part">
        <UserValue title="PartNumber" name="{current()}" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is the solution.

Comment: Beside the fact that i'm not familiar with Attribute value templates yet this looks much easier than mine... However, the conversion from title "part" to "PartNumber" does not work for me. I have checked it with this tool [link](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/#.XKdNjZgzbRY)